# Regarding dependices in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

After running flutter pub get here is the output

[image]

As you see the pay match and pay requires old version of SDK.My current version is Flutter 3.10.6.I tried downgrading it but after that the errors increased,as by that globally its changing.So My question is there any way to use 2 version in same project if yes how,or if any other way please suggest me.

pubspec.yaml 1

[image]

[image: pubspec.yaml 2]

An efficient solution

Comment: can you try with replacing version number with `any`

Comment: Before that on which flutter version code working perfectly?

Comment: Don't poste images of your code, rather paste them here.

Comment: just increase the intl version